# taking care of long filenames

Tags: windows, rdiff-backup

Yesterday I deployed a simple backup based on rdiff-backup on a Windows server machine and our customer had a lot filenames/paths exceeding 250 chars. Every new customer we acquire is having this issue, so my question is, how do you take care of these situations? (there are way too many files to take care of them manually)

Answer (score 9):

Use another backup solution. rdiff-backup got its last update in 2009. Also their website clearly states

> Many users seem to use rdiff-backup on MS Windows but this configuration is less well tested.

That's not what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you have any suggestion of free reliable software with incremental backups?

Comment: What about the builtin Windows Server Backup?

Comment: Don't you think it will kill the machine's performance?

Comment: I did not experience such a thing. But I also prefer to run these backup jobs at night when there is no/minimum load.